# php regex ignoring "S" character

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use the php regex command. My string is

localhost/uploads/125b77ed75d78dcba94f7527c9691c7b6cc20793/

Both the lines below return "1":

```
$dest = "localhost/uploads/125b77ed75d78dcba94f7527c9691c7b6cc20793/";
$res =  preg_match ( '/^localhost\/uploads\/*./' , $dest);
```

and

```
$dest = "localhost/uploads/125b77ed75d78dcba94f7527c9691c7b6cc20793/";
$res =  preg_match ( '/^localhost\/upload\/*./' , $dest);
```

The regex command seems to be ignoring the "s" character entirely. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `*.` is not the same as `.*`. `\/*` matches 0+ `/`, so you do not require a `/` after `upload`, it may go missing, and `.` matches 1 char other than line break chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Right right, thank you!

Comment: are you trying to match the string after "uploads/" if so `(?<=(^localhost[\/]uploads[\/]))(.*)(?=[\/])` would work

Comment: @TomPowis OP just swapped the `.` and `*`, it is a typo question.